# Add a product in my shopping list - Creating a shopping list app

Tags: swift, addition, shopping-cart

I've created a product page. Next to the product name, there is a + button. What is supposed to happen when clicking the + button, the product will be added to my cart. How do I do it? I have tried different ways to do it, for example, when clicking the + button a image of the product will show in the cart. But when I press the button, the app crash and I don't know why... Are there any other options for how to do it?

Here is an image of my product page (left) and my cart (right). 
[image]

Comment: Add the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no outlet between your view controllers. Keep in mind that you can only show one view controller at a time. I can also see that you created a big view controller hardly. You should do it programmatically...

Go on this page : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html , you'll learn how to create Table View, it will be really usefull for what you are trying to do.

Then you will have to pass data between controller so i suggest you go there : https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/

Comment: Thank you! I will go through your links and follow the steps from there. I'm very new to both Swift and programming, so this will probably help me a lot.

Comment: Yes, i think you should take the time to understand this things in swift. Table view may take you some time but it's the only way you can achieve what you are trying to do (I personnally see no other way to do it)

Answer (score 0):

One possibilitie is that you have an outlet in your button that do not reach your view controller. To solve this try right clicking the button and deleting all outlet. The you can connect them again and it should not crash.